# Draw text on ImageView doesn't work

Tags: android

I have extended class from `ImageView` and want some text to be drawn on it. This doesn't work, do you know why? Thank you.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas); 
    int imgWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int imgHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    float txtWidth = mTextPaint.measureText("your text");
    int x = Math.round(imgWidth/2 - txtWidth/2);
    int y = imgHeight/2 - 6; // 6 is half of the text size
    canvas.drawText("your text", x, y, mTextPaint);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setColor(android.R.color.black);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(12);
    mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);}
```

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with dp and pixels, for `setTextSize` is in dp, and `imgWidth`, `imgHeight` in pixels. And log what the values of `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` are.

Comment: Even if I set x and y to zero I'm getting nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code, and immediately got a `Lint` error. In `init()` you are setting your `mTextPaint` to `android.R.color.black`. Because it's a static value, I could immediately see that the actual `int` value of that variable is `0x0106000c`, which is *almost* completely transparent. You should use `getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)` or plain ol' `Color.BLACK`.

Note that a `textSize` of 12 is very, very small. This code shows 12 (albeit very small).

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        init();
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    Paint mTextPaint;

    private void init() {
        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(12);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas); 
        int imgWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int imgHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        float txtWidth = mTextPaint.measureText("your text");
        int x = Math.round(imgWidth/2 - txtWidth/2);
        int y = imgHeight/2 - 6;
        canvas.drawText("12", x, y, mTextPaint);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.example.mytest.MyImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Copy/paste, if problem persist, start logging. Again, this code works, I see `12` on my screen.

Comment: This didn't help unfortunately

Comment: @siik what are the dimensions of your custom View?

Comment: Now I set   mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT); canvas.drawText("12", 0, 0, mTextPaint); Still nothing

Comment: Thanks for a hint, you were right about color and measurements.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to accomplish the desire effect without creating your own class.  Just set the background of a TextView with an image drawable.  See my example with a text in a speech bubble.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textOverImage"
    android:background="@drawable/speech_bubble"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="..."
    android:layout_height="..."
    />
```